# are small SOC chips also affected by Meltdown and Spectre?

Tags: meltdown, spectre, cpu

How can I find out, if given CPU is affected by the Meltdown and Spectre bugs ?

My CPU is relatively older, and it is a `SOC` chip:

```
AMD GX-412TC SOC
```

I was not able to find, whether these chips also use speculative execution:

http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Puma/AMD-G-Series%20GX-412TC.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Ryan Crosby made a [Spectre PoC](https://github.com/crozone/SpectrePoC) that attempts to exploit Spectre, and [ran it succesfully on a AMD GX-412TC SOC](https://github.com/crozone/SpectrePoC#tweaking).